# "code ." no longer working in WSL2 when attempting to open VSCode

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, vscode-remote

I type in the expected `code .` and get the following message:

[image]

Ive tried different "solutions" from other SO posts, but nothing has proven effective. This has just started happening today (8/8/22), and I didn't make any changes that I can recall. Any tips would be greatly appreciated on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I finally got it working by reinstalling VS Code locally. Code was missing from my `%PATH%` environment variable, and I found the `code` command wasn't working locally either. I was able to fix this by reinstalling VS Code. I could probably have just added the installation directory to the `%PATH%` as well, but wanted to make sure everything was properly repaired with a fresh install.

The WSL `init` process appends the Windows `%PATH%` to the Linux `$PATH` by default, so terminating and restarting my WSL distro fixed the issue on WSL.